# Polars: How to find value in previous values by predicate?

Tags: python-polars, array-reverse

How to find "price" of previous 'top'?

```
df = DataFrame({
    'price': [1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2],
    'spikes': [None, None, 'top', None, 'bottom', None, 'top', None]
})
```

In result I want to find value of previous top/bottom price.
Expected result would be:

```
df = DataFrame({
    'price': [1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2],
    'spikes': [None, None, 'top', None, 'bottom', None, 'top', None],
    'prev_spikes_prices: [None, None, None, None, None, None, 4, None]
})
```

Comment: A `fill_null` with an expression is probably the way to go. What is the expected output? I don't understand "third row of previous price".

Comment: @Wayoshi Sorry, added expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this can be solved by grouping by `spikes` and shifting the `price` column by one and since you only want the prices where spikes is not null we add this as `pl.when` condition. See the following code:

```
(df
 .with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col("spikes").is_not_null())
    .then(pl.col("price").shift(1).over("spikes"))
    .otherwise(None).alias("prev_spikes_prices"))
)



shape: (8, 3)
┌───────┬────────┬────────────────────┐
│ price ┆ spikes ┆ prev_spikes_prices │
│ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---                │
│ i64   ┆ str    ┆ i64                │
╞═══════╪════════╪════════════════════╡
│ 1     ┆ null   ┆ null               │
│ 2     ┆ null   ┆ null               │
│ 4     ┆ top    ┆ null               │
│ 2     ┆ null   ┆ null               │
│ 1     ┆ bottom ┆ null               │
│ 2     ┆ null   ┆ null               │
│ 3     ┆ top    ┆ 4                  │
│ 2     ┆ null   ┆ null               │
└───────┴────────┴────────────────────┘
```